# tensorflow custom loss function with additional parameters

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I understand how custom loss functions work in tensorflow. Suppose in the following code , a and b are numbers.

```
def customLoss( a,b):
    
    def loss(y_true,y_pred):    
        loss=tf.math.reduce_mean(a*y_pred + b*y_pred)
        return loss
    return loss
```

But what if a and b are arrays which have the same shape as y_pred.
let's say

```
y_pred= np.array([0,1,0,1])
a= np.arange(4)
b= np.ones(4)
```

I would like to the value of loss function  is equal to 6:

```
np.mean(a*y_pred + b*y_pred) #element-wise.
```

I feel like my loss function is wrong now. It should be two additional inputs or weights of each sample. Can anyone help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `a` and `b` are fixed numbers across all loss computations, you can do something similar to your original loss function:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

y_pred = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
y_true = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
a = np.arange(4)
b = np.ones(4)


def get_custom_loss(a, b):
  a = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.float32)
  b = tf.constant(b, dtype=tf.float32)

  def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.float32)
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, dtype=tf.float32)

    loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(
        [tf.math.multiply(a, y_pred), tf.math.multiply(b, y_pred)])
    return loss

  return loss_fn

loss_fn = get_custom_loss(a, b)
print(loss_fn(y_pred, y_true))
```

`tf.math.multiply(foo, bar)` will perform element-wise multiplication of two tensors (see [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/multiply)). I assume you also want to sum the result of the two products, rather than take the mean (which would be 1.5).

Just a note: you aren't currently using `y_true` in your loss.

Comment: Thank you so much for help ! I just have one more question please. In this case, should I use Functional API or Sequential. In other words , are a and b the inputs of my model? If the answer is Functional. Then how should I specify the input shape. Mine input X is ((10000,100) ( 10000 samples with 100 features). Thanks again. And also the reason why I dont use y_true is because, the training dataset doesn't have labels( unsupervised).

Comment: I generally have a personal preference for the functional api (subclassing a new tf.keras.Model has some annoying implications with regard to checkpointing and other model behavior).

Are your `a` and `b` tensors constant? If so, you do not need to include them as inputs to the model and can use the closure approach from your original example (simply passing the loss function to keras during fit). 

Things are more complicated if they aren't constant and change with each input. I'll need to think about that some more.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think in my case, they are constant . But just like in the example code, each sample X has a different constant. Hence, I wrote 'a = np.arange(4)'. But I would love to know if it's now , then how would I deal with it? Would you happen to have some reference for me to learn this please? Thank you